# Java stream to build Map of Map of sorted list Objects

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am working on a Spring Boot project and have a scenario like below.

I have a table.

```
id | name | category  | sub_category     |
-----------------------------------------
1  | stud1| science   | physics          | 
2  | stud2| science   | maths            |
3  | stud3| arts      | commerce         |
4  | stud4| statistics| computer_science |
5  | stud5| statistics| computer_science |
```

I hit the DB and get the above data and load Student object which contains Id, name, category and subCategory fields.

```
List<Student> studList = studentRepo.findAll();
```

I also have a StudentDto object which is sent in response to caller.

Now I need to create a `Map<category, Map<sub_category, List<StudentDto>>>` and the list should be sorted by Student's name.
I am trying using,

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<StudentDto>>> categoryMap = new HashMap<>();
var studentList = studentRepo.findAll();
studentList.stream().foreach(student -> {
   if (categoryMap.get(student.getCategory()) == null) {
       categoryMap.put(student.getCategory(), new HashMap<String, List<StudentDto>>);
   }
   if (categoryMap.get(student.getCategory()).get(student.getSubCategory()) == null) {
       categoryMap.get(student.getCategory()).put(student.getSubCategory(), new ArrayList<StudentDto>);   
   }
   categoryMap.get(student.getCategory()).get(student.getSubCategory()).add(new StudentDto.builder().name(studenr.getName).build());
});
```

Is there a more efficient way using Java streams that makes the same with fewer lines?

Answer (score 0):

`computeIfAbsent` is your friend:

```
studentList.foreach(student ->
   categoryMap.computeIfAbsent(student.getCategory(),
           x -> new HashMap<String, List<StudentDto>>())
   .computeIfAbsent(student.getSubCategory(), x -> new ArrayList<StudentDto>())   
   .add(new StudentDto.builder().name(studenr.getName).build()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go through below solution:

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<StudentDto>>> categoryMap = studentList.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getCategory,
                      Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getSubCategory,
                      Collectors.mapping(StudentDto::fromStudent, 
                      Collectors.toList()))));
    
System.out.println(categoryMap);
```

- As per StudentDto class all the fields will be used through the stream.
- Over here created one map based on your requirement like String key and  List as value.
- Collectors.groupingBy is used for grouping objects by some property, so here we are using category and subcategory.
- Collectors.mapping is used for convert Dto values to the finalized list.
- Finally printed that map using Java Standard way for print.

Answer (score 0):

```java
Map<String, Map<String, List<StudentDto>>> map = students.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                        it -> it.category, // group by category
                        Collectors.groupingBy( // downstream
                                it -> it.sub_category, // group by sub_category
                                Collectors.mapping( // downstream
                                        it -> new StudentDto(it.id, it.name, it.category, it.sub_category), // convert student to studentDto, change it to your code
                                        Collectors.toList() // downstream
                                )
                        )
                )
        );
```

TEST

```java
List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>() {{
    add(new Student(1, "stud1", "science", "physics"));
    add(new Student(2, "stud2", "science", "maths"));
    add(new Student(3, "stud3", "arts", "commerce"));
    add(new Student(4, "stud4", "statistics", "computer_science"));
    add(new Student(5, "stud5", "statistics", "computer_science"));
}};

Map<String, Map<String, List<StudentDto>>> map = students.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                        it -> it.category,
                        Collectors.groupingBy(it -> it.sub_category, Collectors.mapping(it -> new StudentDto(it.id, it.name, it.category, it.sub_category), Collectors.toList()))
                )
        );
assert map.size() == 3;

Map<String, List<StudentDto>> scienceMap = map.get("science");
assert scienceMap.size() == 2;
assert scienceMap.get("physics").size() == 1;
assert scienceMap.get("physics").getFirst().id == 1;
assert scienceMap.get("maths").size() == 1;
assert scienceMap.get("maths").getFirst().id == 2;

Map<String, List<StudentDto>> artsMap = map.get("arts");
assert artsMap.size() == 1;
assert artsMap.get("commerce").size() == 1;
assert artsMap.get("commerce").getFirst().id == 3;

Map<String, List<StudentDto>> statisticsMap = map.get("statistics");
assert statisticsMap.size() == 1;
assert statisticsMap.get("computer_science").size() == 2;
assert statisticsMap.get("computer_science").getFirst().id == 4;
assert statisticsMap.get("computer_science").getLast().id == 5;
```